# Amazon SQS returns random quantity of messages

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I have connected Amazon SP-API with Amazon SQS, to get notifications about new orders. I got needed notifications to the SQS, but for some reason when I try to receive those notifications from my App, all time I got:

1. Random quantity of messages in the response. If I make 3 requests, the first can return 2 messages, the second 1 message, and the third 5 messages.
2. All time it's less than the value of MaxNumberOfMessages (I set 10), but I have more than 30 messages in the SQS.

Here is my code that I use to get notifications to my App:

```
        $queueUrl = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/XXXXXXX";
        $credentials = new Credentials(env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'));

        $client = new SqsClient([
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => $credentials,
        ]);

        try {
            $result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
                'AttributeNames' => ['SentTimestamp'],
                'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 10,
                'MessageAttributeNames' => ['All'],
                'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl, // REQUIRED
                'WaitTimeSeconds' => 20
            ));
            $messages = $result->get('Messages');
```

How can I get at least 10 messages in 1 request? Why it's so randomly?

Comment: *"How can I get at least 10 messages in 1 request?"* - you can't. *"Why it's so randomly?"* - because it is a highly distributed service and designed in a way that this is the result.

Comment: @luk2302 how is it possible at all?? All that I need it to get 10 messages in 1 request when I have 10+ messages in SQS. It's something absolutely basic..

Comment: No, that is fundamentally not how SQS works. That is very much **not** basic in terms of distributed systems. What you want is simply not possible, end of discussion. If you have a few 1000 messages in the queue it is likely you only get 10 messages per request but still not guaranteed.